# Angular2 variable binds but at the same time shows error 'could not read property of undefined'

Tags: javascript, angular, binding

I have an Angular2 UserEditComponent which has two private fields: user and test. user is of type User, where a "login" field is defined. The user is retrieved from a rest endpoint and test set in the controller.

COMPONENT:

```
export class UserEditComponent implements OnInit {

    private user: User;
    private test: String;


    ngOnInit() {
        this.test = 'TEST';
        this.route.params
        .map(params => +params['userId'])
        .switchMap(
            userId => this.userService.getById(userId)
        )
        .subscribe((user: User) => {
            this.user = user;
            this.test = 'TEST';
        });
    }
}
```

The UserEditComponent has a template. The template references both: user and test.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="test">TEST</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="test [(ngModel)]="test" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Login</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username [(ngModel)]="user.login" required />
</div>
```

The browser does show the string "TEST" in the test input field and the user's login String, e. g. his email address, but also throws the exception

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12813)
    at checkAndUpdateView (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12151)
    at callViewAction (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12514)
    at execComponentViewsAction (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12446)
    at checkAndUpdateView (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12157)
    at callViewAction (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12514)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction at checkAndUpdateView  (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12152)
    at callViewAction (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12514)
```

**ANSWER**

As was pointed out in one of the answers from the post linked in the comments, the variable user is instanciated only after the asynchronous call to the rest endpoint has returned and is thus indeed undefined when the view is rendered. The solution is to wrap the whole block into an *ngIf="user"

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="user">
    <label for="username">Login</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username [(ngModel)]="user.login" required />
</div>
```

Comment: You can add the answer yourself separately from the question block. It makes it clear that the question has been resolved that way. Also, since the comments have been cleaned up we don't know what was previously discussed.